# Meaning of 1000L

Tags: network-interface

I have a question on this code. what does the 1000L * 8L represents?

Example:
bytesRec += networkInterfaces[i].GetIPv4Statistics().BytesReceived / 1000L * 8L;

Sorry new to here

Thank you

Comment: This code is to grab bytes receive

Comment: ...and the language is... - In a lot of languages, appending an L treats the value as a long.

Comment: Here are examples specified in C# http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix

Answer (score 1):

Suffixes specify number types. They instruct the C# compiler that an integral literal such as 1000 be considered a certain type of number—for example, a long (1000L)